# how can we change image view background on swipe?

Tags: android, swipe, gesture

As a example,have to draw a layout of images.

I inflated an `ImageView` into a layout. When I swipe on the screen I need  to change the color of the each circle to green. How should I do it. I tried with gesture detector, but I can't get what I need.

[image: screen shot]

and this is my code.. I create this view by inflating an image view..

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(1024);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        count = width/30;
        totalCircles = count * (height/30);
        horizontalSpace = width%30;
        verticalSpace = height%30;
        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.fl);
        mRelativeLayout.setPadding(horizontalSpace/2, verticalSpace/2, horizontalSpace/2, verticalSpace/2);
        for(int i=1;i<totalCircles+1;i++){
             myButton = new ImageView(this);
             myButton.setId(i);
             myButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_grey);
             LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(0,0);
             if(i%count != 1){
                 lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imgViews.get(i-2).getId()); 
                 if(imView != null){
                     lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imView.getId()); 
                 }
                 if(i%count == 0){
                     imView = myButton;
                 }
             }else{
                 if(imView != null){
                     lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imView.getId()); 
                 }
             }

             mRelativeLayout.addView(myButton,lp);
             myButton.getLayoutParams().width = 30;
             myButton.getLayoutParams().height = 30;
             imgViews.add(myButton);
             myButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                     if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                         System.out.println("Inside touch listener");
                            ImageView imV = (ImageView)v;
                            imV.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_green);
                     }

                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to change color of this circles to green when i swipe over  the each circles as similar to what we do to unlock a phhone using pattern...

Comment: Why in the world are you using relative layout out? Just use a Tablelayout or GridView.

Comment: do you have this code in github? I need a implementation like this for a solution to my job...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jack K Fouani's  answer is partially correct. Instead of `imagView.onTouch` you need to use `gridview.onTouch`.
Please check this sample.

```
gv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float currentXPosition = event.getX();
            float currentYPosition = event.getY();
            int position = gv.pointToPosition((int)currentXPosition, (int) currentYPosition);
            //using the position obtained you can change the imageview color.           
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inflating one ImageView. You should fill a GridView where every GridCell contains a circle image. Now
set the OnTouchEvent of those Gridcells to change the ImageView within the GridCell.

Comment: But i need to detect back and forward movements as well as diagonal movements also.. is it possible with gridview??

Answer (score 0):

my advice is to use `GrideView` with adapter , inside the adapter you will have `position` for each `imagView` the position allow you to check if image is touched or not depending on that you can change `ImageView` color to white or green

Comment: is imageview will select when i swipe on the screen

Comment: yes as i said set `imagView.onTouch` check if already touched then make it white if not make it green , and you can place check by array and the picture position inside adapter will be the key inside array to check

Comment: thanks Jack, ur answer give me a fire. I used touch event with grid view as mahesh said

Comment: ;) glad you've found ur way